# Wavelets vs Fourier Transforms

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing, wavelets

It's supposed that computing a spectrogram for a signal is faster using wavelets. However, wavelets need to be applied to the signal for every time step *and* frequency, giving the implementation a time complexity of $O(t*f)$; however, using the STFT process, we only need to apply the fourier transform over each time step (generating all frequencies composing the windowed signal) - $O(t)$.

Is wavelet convolution over a signal for a specific frequency significantly faster than a fast fourier transform of a time step (window) in the signal?

Comment: The computational complexity is of secondary importance:  *WHY* choose one over the other?  THAT is what you should answer in any particular case.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It's been proven that both methods produce effectively the same results. So, I'm comparing performance

Comment: "Same result"?  False.  Just look at the profound differences between JPEG (Fourier) versus JPEG 2000 (wavelet).

Comment: See this paper http://tratamientodesenales-fiunam.weebly.com/uploads/4/4/6/5/44651607/fourier_hilbert__wavelet-based_signal_analysis_bruns_2004.pdf

Comment: @DavidG.Stork what JPEGs are you referring to?

Comment: @Tobi JPEG and JPEG-2000 are two different image coding standards. The first one uses DCT blocks of 8x8 pixels which are kind of compareable to STFT and the second one uses DWT. They have both different performance as well as different properties.

Comment: @mathreadler To produce `effectively the same result`

Comment: None the less, my question is about performance rather than their equivalence

Comment: But they don't. Otherwise there would have been no purpose of creating Jpeg-2000.

Comment: @mathreadler Better compression performance would be the obvious reason. Looking at the images, they're `effectively the same result`

Comment: The differences between JPEG and JPEG 2000 compression schemes (the computational foundations for the latter were developed in my lab) are profound.  JPEG 2000 has lossy and lossless versions, is incremental, reversible, avoids "blockies," and many other differences from traditional JPEG.  Oh... and compression ratios for different classes of images.

Comment: @Tobi No. The main feature was **not** better compression performance, but scalability.

Comment: Correct.  The main benefits for JPEG-2000 were other than compression ratio.

Comment: This question has virtually nothing to do with the JPEG formats. `[JPEG] uses DCT blocks of 8x8 pixels which are kind of compareable to STFT` - I'm asking which *real* STFT and Wavelets on a signal.

Comment: I'm uninterested by the two's in/equivalence (or the JPEG formats' equivalences) - though I've already referenced a paper proving their interoperability.